# Unable to Move Out of ViewPort Pane - Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the webpage "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/exit_intent" where if we move out of the Viewpane towards the top of the page then the pop up window appear with a message. But I am unable to do it with the help of selenium, is there any way we can perform this action?

Comment: Also add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code: This is using Robot class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.awt.*;

public class stackOverFlowQs {
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/exit_intent");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove(600,0);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ouibounce-modal']/div[2]/div[3]/p")).click();
    }
}
```

This is using Actions:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class stackOverFlowQs {
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/exit_intent");
        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h3"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(e).moveByOffset(600,-1).build().perform();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ouibounce-modal']/div[2]/div[3]/p")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sudha Velan, I actually did it with Robot Class, but looking for the answers to do it with Actions only. I have tried your suggestion but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @ChetanSharma I m very sure it will work..Because i have ran and then only posted here.

Comment: `.moveByOffset()` moves the mouse from its last known position and since you haven't set the mouse position with the script, it's going to behave inconsistently. If you find an element, e.g. the h3 tag, and then move the mouse to that element before `.moveByOffset()` it works consistently.

Comment: I updated the code and removed the unnecessary sleeps.

Comment: @SudhaVelan I think if you try to move out of the viewport through `Actions` definitely you will see `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure - While executing the Test case Your mouse pointer should be at middle of the window[surface]. not above the URL part.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is working , using the webrowser Chrome :

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveByOffset(600, -1).build().perform();
```

This is not working for me:

```
action.moveToElement(e).moveByOffset(600,-1).build().perform();
```