# Unable to access modal window , actions not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate this website http://the-internet.herokuapp.com where i have to go to http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/exit_intent and hover out of viewport pane so that a modal window appears.

I am not sure how to do this , i tried actions assuming when i go to top right the modal window appears and hence trying to hover around that image but it isnt working.

here is actions code-

driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/exit_intent");

Actions ACTION = new Actions(driver);

ACTION.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://github.com/tourdedave/the-internet']/img"))).build().perform();

I am not sure how to do this , any help is higly appreciated.

This is the URL -http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/exit_intent.

I tried searching SO but unable to find appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.switchTo().frame("modalframname");`
Then your code `.frame` will switch u to that frame and u can perform a test on it.

Comment: Hope it will work

Comment: you can do this when modal window is displayed , but for that i need to move out of viewport pane, Anyway the solution given on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139536/unable-to-move-out-of-viewport-pane-selenium has worked for me. Thanks anyways!!